# AWS Glue vs Zaloni metadata management

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, data-lake

What is the value add of a solution such as Zaloni over AWS Glue in terms of metadata harvesting/management?

Are use cases for Zaloni specific to Hadoop? What if the Data Lake were based on S3 + RDS'?

Comment: Zaloni is not an AWS service, so if you're asking for a recommendation, that's off topic for Stackoverflow

Comment: no, my question is more fundamental. Is Zaloni appropriate for non-Hadoop data lakes?

Comment: You would have to ask the Zaloni sales team